# facebook like button makes whole page blink white on page load

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using a facebook like button in a navbar on top of my site. When I load any page on a password protected dev version of my site, the whole page loads halfway, then blinks white, then loads again. Is this just caused by fbook trying to see the URL and not making it past the login/password?

It's a totally standard facebook button with the fbook root div and the js. my site is just regular php/html. What is the first thing I should do to figure out the problem?

Comment: https is not cached and slower than http, scripts are loaded sync, adding css to the dom causes repaint, and who knows whatever else their JS file does...

Comment: This issue is recent. I have this exact issue as of an hour ago.

Comment: Same issue here as well, just started happening.

Comment: Like button currently seems to have issues, it might be the same issue as reported here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/486785918148603/ Go subscribe to that bug if you think this matches your problem (more subscribers to the bug means higher priority.)